# Close popup after button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have below code in popup. I want to close this popup when user clicks on export button,

```
Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Try           
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim w As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        gv.RenderControl(w)

        Dim content As String = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString()

        'I have generate pdf code here
        'I want to close this popup       
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried IF 'Event when your Button gets pressed' then unload 'your popup'

Comment: Using `Close()` will close the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "winclose", "window.close();", true);
```

It generates client-side JavaScript that will close current window when rendered.